# Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

I'm running docker behind a corporate proxy with the following versions:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.2
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.8
 Git commit:        6a30dfc
 Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:29:11 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.2
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.8
  Git commit:       6a30dfc
  Built:            Thu Aug 29 05:27:45 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.6
  GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8
  GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

On a Ubuntu 18.04 Server.

I have configured the proxy correctly and docker seems to be using it. However, any `docker login` or `docker pull hello-world` invocations lead to a `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure`.

I have installed the corporate root certificate to local trust stores and it seems to be working alright as depicted by the following openssl output when I run:

```
openssl s_client -proxy proxy:3128 -connect registry-1.docker.io:443 -showcerts
```

**Redacted Certificates**

---

```
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: DH, 1024 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 6586 bytes and written 546 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 7D9CA79CAB0343D8F2B4B2288FCF0CC98721AC07C0FCBAB39BC6E344E5C1E658
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: E841987D8259CD5BB07C5BE4918A64BA10B9D5DE49352A2367B7AE00F4A482205E6ED7C1C8ECAB56D136C54FD943049F
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1568137963
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Anybody have any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Comment: I have exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this too using docker:dind and posted about it here https://discourse.drone.io/t/docker-dind-image-behind-a-proxy/7833

What I have just discovered is that if I use docker:18.06.0-dind then it works.  I think maybe the later versions of docker are using tls ciphers which your proxy does not support.  This guy talks about this https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2922#issuecomment-444431310

You can get information about your proxy's tls by pointing a browser using it at https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html

I'm going to try and sort out my proxy (squid) so it supports docker 19 if I manage to I'll post here.

more info:

here https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/487

here https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-behing-transparent-proxy-and-intermediate-cert/74860/4